# Symfony error message (An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000])

Tags: php, sql, symfony, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to create a blog with symfony and I'm new in this field, I can’t solve the error that appears to me and I don’t understand where it comes from:

An exception occurred while executing a query:

```
SQLSTATE\[23000\]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: articles.users_id
```

**Articles.php**

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ArticlesRepository::class)]
class Articles implements TimestampedInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $titre;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Groups('article')]
    private $slug;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text')]
    private $contenu;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    #[Groups('article')]
    private $created_at;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    private $updated_at;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Users::class, inversedBy: 'articles')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private $users;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'articles', targetEntity: Commentaires::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private $commentaires;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: MotsCles::class, inversedBy: 'articles')]
    private $mots_cles;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Categories::class, inversedBy: 'articles')]
    private $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->commentaires = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->mots_cles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() : ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

ArticlesCrudController.php

```
class ArticlesCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Articles::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        yield IdField::new('id');
        yield TextField::new('titre');

        yield TextEditorField::new('contenu');

        yield DateTimeField::new('created_at')->hideOnForm();
        yield DateTimeField::new('updated_at')->hideOnForm();


    }

}
```

DashBoardController.php

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{   public function __construct(private AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator){

    }
    #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $url = $this->adminUrlGenerator->setController(ArticlesCrudController::class)->generateUrl();

        return $this->redirect($url);
    }


    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('BLOG DE HIBA');
    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', '');
        yield MenuItem::subMenu('Articles', '')->setSubItems([
            MenuItem::linkToCrud('Tous les articles' , 'fas fa-book',Articles::class),
            MenuItem::linkToCrud('Ajouter' , 'fas fa-plus',Articles::class)->setAction(Crud::PAGE_NEW),
            MenuItem::linkToCrud('Categories' , 'fas fa-tag',Categories::class),
            MenuItem::linkToCrud('MotsCles' , 'fas fa-tag',MotsCles::class)
        ]);
        yield MenuItem::subMenu('Utilisateurs', '')->setSubItems([
            MenuItem::linkToCrud('Utilisateurs' , 'fas fa-user',Users::class),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please I need Help, any suggestion would be great!!!

An exception occurred while executing a query:

```
SQLSTATE\[23000\]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: articles.users_id
```

Comment: Are you using EasyAdminBundle? If yes which version?

Comment: Yes, EasyAdmin 4